# Hiera + Puppet classes

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to figure out Puppet (3.0) and how it relates to built-in Hiera. So this is what I tried, an extremely simple example (I'll make a more complex hierarchy when I manage to get the simple one working):

```
# /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - common
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata

# /etc/puppet/hieradata/common.yaml
test::param: value

# /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/init.pp
class test ($param) { notice($param) }

# /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
include test
```

If I directly apply it, it's fine:

```
$ puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
Scope(Class[Test]): value
```

If I go through puppet master, it's not fine:

```
$ puppet agent --test
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Must pass param to Class[Test] at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:1 on node <nodename>
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:

I just left the office but a thought struck me: I should probably restart puppet master so it can see the new hiera.conf. I'll try that on Monday; in the meantime, if anyone figures out some not-it problem, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Good review of the implicit lookup in Kelsey's talk from Puppet conf 2012: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9TK-gUNFHk (at 38mns) - however,  I had some issues with this feature: https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/17463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot, and the edit in the question was correct: after restarting puppet master, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For **Hiera** ( /etc/puppet/environments/local/hieradata/hostgroups/base/yourhostname/all.yaml )

---

mySuperVariable: lalala

For **Init** ( /etc/puppet/environments/local/manifests/yourhostname/manifest )

class mimir::init {
   $myvariable = hiera('mySuperVariable', 'fallbackValue')
}

For **Template** ( /etc/puppet/environments/local/manifests/yourhostname/templates )

whatever ...  <%= myvariable%> blahblah

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I was trying to figure out the implicit lookup, without using the `hiera` function. Also, the title explicitly mentions classes, and implicitly modules.